# Могу ли я как-то показать MessageBox в своем приложении, при убивании процесса в диспетчере задач?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно, чтобы при "убивании" процесса моего приложения через диспетчер задач появлялся MessageBox. Возможно ли такое ? Пробовал через `CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing`, но работает только, если снимать задачу.

Comment: Вряд ли. Если вообще приходит хоть какое-то уведомление в программе об этом действии (в чём также сомневаюсь), то можно попробовать вызывать отдельную программку с нужным окошком.

Comment: Нет, перехватить это событие нельзя. Иначе легко можно создать неубиваемый процесс.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При старте своего приложения запускаете ещё один процесс, который мониторит состояние вашего приложения. И если приложение убили через диспетчер задач, он повторно его запускает. При этом можно показать MessageBox, но само приложение в любом случае не спасти.

В свою очередь, основное приложение мониторит состояние этого процесса, и тоже перезапускает его при убийстве.

Однако, за такое нужно отрубать руки и отлучать от компьютера.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!